# Can I fit Core i7 4790 processor in Asus ROG Strix Z270F motherboard?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

Here is my CPU:
https://ark.intel.com/products/80806/Intel-Core-i7-4790-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_00-GHz

And I have this GPU:
https://www.asus.com/Graphics-Cards/ROG-STRIX-GTX1050TI-O4G-GAMING/specifications/

I want to buy this motherboard:
https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-Z270F-GAMING/specifications/

Is it okay to use this motherboard?

Comment: What do the specifications say on the motherboard regarding CPU support? We are unable to answer your hardware purchase questions. Please read here: [ask]

Comment: The links I provided have the specifications. Should I copy them in here?

Comment: My point exactly. Why aren’t you reading them? Shopping help is off topic. If you want to reword your question to be “How do I know if a cpu will work with a motherboard” then it would be on topic. But we can’t help you shop for parts. That’s your job to research, learn and decide. Parts go obsolete before I press ENTER on my keyboard. I’m here to help you learn, but not do the work for you. No offense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you're processor I7-4790 is not compatible with that board. Your board has a 1151 socket while your cpu has a 1150 socket. You'll have to change one or the other.

If its the cpu you want to change you can use this one : I7-7700
[https://www.amazon.com/Intel-i7-7700-Processor-Frequency-Generation/dp/B01N0L41N7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N0L41N7) 
That one is a 1151 and is compatible with your board. Btw, that graphic is compatible too.

Comment: Sorry, but I can not change CPU. I can only choose the motherboard.

Comment: Can you suggest a suitable motherboard?

Comment: you could go with an ASUS Z97-A LGA 1150 Intel Z97. But good luck finding one online. They are getting out of stock. Maybe a local pc store which can order one.